# how to install mcamara/laravel-localization in laravel 11?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

when i installed it why can't show the kernal.php in app>http ??

where i put this :

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    /**
    * The application's route middleware.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        /**** OTHER MIDDLEWARE ****/
        'localize'                => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
        'localizationRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
        'localeSessionRedirect'   => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
        'localeCookieRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
        'localeViewPath'          => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Laravel 11, the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file no longer exists. Instead, you can register your middleware classes inside the callback of `withMiddleware()` inside `bootstrap/app.php` files.

Inside the `withMiddleware()` method, you can use the `alias()` method of the `Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware` class to register your middleware classes' aliases.

Here's an example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'localize'                => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
            'localizationRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
            'localeSessionRedirect'   => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
            'localeCookieRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
            'localeViewPath'          => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();
```

More information available in the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#middleware-aliases